# Is there any way to disable and enable device in windows 95/98?

Tags: windows, windows-98, windows-95

I have an old industrial PC with windows 95/98 installed. For some reason I need to have an script or utility which can disable, wait for few seconds and then enable a device (serial port controller). I can do it manually using Windows Device Manager, checking 'Disable in this hardware profile' checkbox, pushing OK, then unchecking this checkbox. Is there any way to do this from command line or maybe with WinAPI? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this via registry!

When you disable hardware, a key for it will appear in `HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG/Enum/[BUS NAME]/[HARDWARE IDS]/[DEVICE IDS]` with a `CSConfigFlags` value of `01 00 00 00`. This value changes to `00 00 00 00` when you enable the device back.

You can export two `.reg` files and use command line to apply them to the registry